# Looking for the perfect laptop/barebone/all-in-one device

Tags: laptop, all-in-one

I am looking for a device half laptop, half all-in-one, half barebone, to adjust the price to my exact needs. You can see it as either:

- Non-touchscreen, non-iOS/Android, long-hours directly chargable tablet with some adjustable stand
- Non-touchscreen, <21", portable all-in-one
- Laptop without a keyboard

Do you know if I can find something in 2015 close to this specs? What I am searching is an:

- All-In-One (Screen with an internal computer), crafted with portability in mind, preferredly

**With:**

- Good display: I am going to use it for developing long hours, and I have some eyesight problems. 15"-17" would be perfect, Ergonomics are important so I'd expect an adjustable stand (or a third-party compatible base) to make it perpendicular to my body when placed over the table
- Good performance: an i5 at least, not ridicule RAM and an SSD is a must (128Gb at least)

The thing is I wanted it as minimal/barebone as possible, **I don't need**:

- Powerful graphic card: I am not a graphic designer nor 3D renderer
- OS nor Bloatware: Just like barebone NUCs, I'll install Ubuntu myself
- Touchscreen
- Bluetooth
- Webcam
- Microphone
- Keyboard nor mouse (I'll buy some ergonomical on my own)
- fancy sound output (I would even rennounce to it)
- SD Cards, ID readers, fingerprints and so on...

I have a large desktop media center for all those fancy media uses.

Just a screen-pc with a bunch of USB 3.0 ports and a Wi-Fi.
That should allow me to get a good deal with acceptable horsepower, if it existed.

Thank you for assisting me and pointing to any brand or model! :)

Comment: Sounds very niche. Apparently, no one thought to not include a touchscreen on an AiO yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible way:

- Akasa Euler S (~$120)
- Some Thin-ITX board (~$150)
- 90W power brick, same as used for HP/Dell laptops (~$20)

Add whichever screen, CPU, RAM, and SSD you like; attach the Akasa case behind the monitor and you're done.

Comment: Thank you! I already have a Zotac and probably a NUC replacement soon. But I am looking for something integrated with screen but without peripherals (a la All-In-One). The problem is that most all-in-ones aare not portable, bigger than 17" and also you need to pay for the touchscreen feature. The later is appliable to most tablets, which also are shipped with android/ios systems.